# Go equivalent to std::set?

Tags: containers, go

What would be the equivalent in Go to a `std::set`? Note that only uniqueness is important, I don't care about ordering.

I've considered using dummy type, such as `map[string]bool` (where `bool` is the dummy), however often I find in Go I need to provide a type where one is not required, such as a channel used as a semaphore, and this case. Am I missing something idiomatic to Go?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using a map with dummy values as a set is common practice in languages like Perl, which do not have sets. I think it is an acceptable way to get sets in Go, unless you want to implement it yourself or use some third-party implementation. Of course, your datatype has to be one that is allowed as the key in a map, i.e. not struct, array, or slice.

Answer (score 3):

Using `map[string]bool` is perfectly fine.

There are also some more fancy libraries to handle sets, see for example: https://github.com/pwil3058/gosets

But I would still stick with a simple map, it is more idiomatic and simpler, which is always good.

Comment: The link is broken.

Answer (score 2):

Using `map[string]bool` (with `true` as the dummy value) or `map[string]struct{}` as a set is considered idiomatic Go. Each of them has its own pros and cons.

Assume:

```golang
b := make(map[string]bool)
s := make(map[string]struct{})
```

1. Checking whether a set has an element is easier with `b`:

   ```golang
   if b["x"] {
       // b has "x"
   }

   if _, ok := s["x"]; ok {
       // s has "x"
   }
   ```
2. Unless you can guarantee that `b` does not have any `false` values, iterating over the elements is easier with `s`:

   ```golang
   for e, v := range b {
       if v {
           // e is an element of b
       }
   }

   for e := range s {
       // e is an element of s
   }
   ```
3. `s` is more memory-efficient than `b`.

As an alternative, you can use an open-source library. For instance:

- [`github.com/soroushj/menge`](https://github.com/soroushj/menge) implements sets of all basic types.
- [`k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/util/sets`](https://pkg.go.dev/k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/util/sets) implements sets of integers (`byte`, `int`, `int32`, `int64`) and strings.

Of course, currently, it's not possible to implement generic sets in Go. But with the [planned](https://blog.golang.org/generics-next-step) addition of generics to Go, it will be possible in a later version (no earlier than 1.17).

Answer (score 0):

If anyone need a set of `int`, you can use this:

```
package main
import "golang.org/x/tools/container/intsets"

func main() {
   var (
      a intsets.Sparse
      b bool
   )
   b = a.Insert(9)
   println(b) // true
   b = a.Insert(9)
   println(b) // false
}
```

https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/tools/container/intsets